# How can I get the URL of a request after a ConnectionError?

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest

I've recently been trying to make a program that returns the URL that a shortened URL (such as bit.ly and t.co URLs) leads to using the Python Requests library.  I've been able to do this easily with working URLs using this method:

```
reveal = requests.get(shortenedUrl, timeout=5)
fullUrl = reveal.url
```

However, when the shortened URL points to a URL that is not real (example: http://thisurldoesnotexistyet.com/), the method above returns a ConnectionError as expected.  The ConnectionError returns this:
 `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='thisurldoesnotexistyet.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000213DC97F588>, 'Connection to thisurldoesnotexistyet.com timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))`

When this happened, I tried this method to get the redirect URL:

```
try:
    reveal = requests.get(shortenedUrl, timeout=5)
    fullUrl = reveal.url
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as error:
    fullUrl = "http://" + error.host
```

However, the method did not work (`AttributeError: 'ConnectTimeout' object has no attribute 'host'`).  Is there any way for me to get the URL that the shortened URL redirects to from the error?

Comment: What do you mean by host? What are expecting from there exactly? The host is the url you tried to connect to. And since the connection timeout the host is not valid or is offline. I don't understand your question. `error.host` is where you get your second error, `error` has no `.host`.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues By host I meant where it says `host='thisurldoesnotexistyet.com'` in the ConnectionError.  I am trying to get `thisurldoesnotexistyet.com` from the error considering I would not have the URL beforehand from a shortened URL and using reveal.url would not work.

Comment: From the code you post, this can only happen in `requests.get(shortenedUrl, timeout=5)`. `shortenedUrl` **is** your _host_. If that is not your problem, post the code that is raising the error.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I've edited my question to better describe my problem.  Host definitely was not the best way to describe what I'm trying to find.  I'm trying to get the URL that the initial host (shortenedUrl) redirects to.  This is displayed in the ConnectionError (`host='thisurldoesnotexistyet.com'`) but I'm unsure of how to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting a url that **does not** exists. Hence you get a timeout.

```py
>>> requests.get('https://does-not-exist')
... (suppressed for clarity)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='does-not-exist', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6b6dba7210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

The **host** is the url you passed in. You can catch the exception and see the same url you passed in, but **you** passed the url to `requests.get`.

```py
>>> try:
...     requests.get('https://does-not-exist')
... except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as error:
...     print(error.request.url)
...
https://does-not-exist/
```